# WebStorm wrong import with react-native-web?

Tags: react-native, webstorm

Trying to work with a react native app, I am using Webstorm 2019.3.4 with a simple blank react-native app project created with `expo init myProject`

Whenever i use react-native components such as `<Text>`, WebStorm offers the auto-import funcitonnality

However, the component is imported from the wrong lib. It pulls it from `react-native-web` instead of `react-native`

Heres the default package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
   "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
   "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
   ...
```

How is the auto-import working here ? How can i switch to react-native import ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, please add `react-native-web/**/*` to the **Do not import exactly from...** list in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript - Imports**.
For code completion with auto import for the native React Native components, please vote for this issue and follow it for the updates: [WEB-35144](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35144)

Comment: Thank you lena.
This does not completely solves the problem since WebStorm is not showing any imports after adding react-native-web/**/* to Do not import. Will follow up on WEB-35144

Comment: This does not work for me, still imports from "react-native-web"